# How to wrap all elements that are next to each other and have the same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, grouping, wrapall

I would like to know how to wrap all elements that are next to each other and have the same class. `.wrapAll()` didn't work since it pushes the paragraph to the bottom.

Source:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="group"></div>
  <div class="group"></div>
  <div class="group"></div>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>

  <div class="group"></div>
  <div class="group"></div>
  <div class="group"></div>
</div>
```

Desired output:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="group-wrapper">
    <div class="group"></div>
    <div class="group"></div>
    <div class="group"></div>
  </div>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>

  <div class="group-wrapper">
    <div class="group"></div>
    <div class="group"></div>
    <div class="group"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: for this specific structure ? or work in other cases as well ?

Comment: I need a solution that will work in all cases.  There could be other elements other than a single paragraph between the groups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to break it to groups between the non-matching elements.

```
$(function(){
    $.fn.reverse = [].reverse;
    var target = '.group', // the class of the elements to group
        invert = ':not(' + target + ')', // we create the invert to find the breakpoints
        wrap = '<div class="group-wrapper">', // what to wrap with
        breakpoints = $('.container > *'+invert); // find the breakpoints in our container

   breakpoints.each(function(){
        $(this).nextUntil(invert).wrapAll( wrap ); // get the matching elements efter this breakpoint and wrap them
    });

    breakpoints.first().prevUntil(invert).reverse().wrapAll( wrap ); // wrap the elements before the first breakpoint

});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/qz53fggd/

Comment: why is order changing in first wrapper? Seems like prevUntil/wrapAll combo is prepending the elements in reverse order or something

Comment: i guess prevUntil builds collection from bottom up, then indexing for wrapAll is reversed

Comment: @charlietfl i am starting from the breakpoints. So if the first break point has elements before it they will be caught by that special case. All others are handled by the `.each()` part

Comment: right I follow the logic, it's the inversion of the elements in the first group that's interesting 3-2-1 rather than 1-2-3

Comment: @charlietfl *blush*.. i hadn't even noticed that behaviour. The `prevAll` and `prevUntil` return the matched elements in closest to furthest order. Updated answer that fixes this.

Comment: struck me as strange (and unexpected) behavior though

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach based on elements being children

```
var $container =$('.container');
function wrapGroup( target, $container){
    // wrap until next non group element
    var $groups = $container.children(target)
    if($groups.length){        
        $groups.first().nextUntil(':not('+target+')').andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="group-wrap">') 
    }
    // check if more group as children and do it again
    if($container.children(target).length){
        wrapGroup( target, $container);
    }    
}
//usage
wrapGroup('.group', $container);
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qdpvg3qp/)**</kbd>